# How to pass a multiline JSON string as an argument to Python script?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need to pass a multiline json (pretty formatted JSON) as an argument to one of my python script. Any way to do so ?

Comment: Can you provide what the object looks like now in your code, what you tried to do, and the error that you got?

Comment: if the json is too big, better read from file

Comment: Pass as an string and then parse it into python variable. Or create REST endpoint to pass JSON and write your login on the REST endpoint method. Please post your code what you have tried so far.

Comment: This JSON will be output of another script. And I don't want to write to file and read from thers.

Answer (score 0):

Pass a filespec instead with the path to your JSON file:

```
import json
import sys

filespec = sys.argv[1]

with open(filespec) as f:
    data = json.load(f)
    print(data)
```

Then call this script: `python myscript.py /path/to/file.json`

Answer (score 0):

> Store the JSON in file and pass it to the code. eg. data.json
>   You can then parse it json.loads(file)

Put the data in a prettyfile.json

```
import sys
import json

def readfile(file):
    with open(file, 'r') as f:
        data_dict = json.load(f)
        // enter code here

if __name__ == "__main__":
    read_file(sys.argv[0])
```

> `python file.py prettyjson.json`